# php if + or statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I've been trying the following:

```
 <?php if ((!is_page(9)) || (!is_page(52))) : ?>
 <?php if (!is_page(9) || !is_page(52)) : ?>
```

But the moment I add the || the if stops working and only the `else` displays

I want to accomplish this: do this on page 9 or page 52

What is the error here?

Comment: I want to accomplish this: do this on page 9 or page 52

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your condition:

```
(!is_page(9) || !is_page(52))
```

Translates to this:

```
!(is_page(9) && is_page(52))
```

This can of course never be true, a page can't be two things at the same time :)

> I want to accomplish this: do this on page 9 or page 52

Just remove the negation and you should be fine:

```
if (is_page(9) || is_page(52)) {
    // do something
} else { 
    // this was not 9 nor 52
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(is_page(9) || is_page(52)) { /* Do this */ }
else { /* Do other stuff */ }
```

|| - OR

&& - AND

Comment: The `)` bracket at the end is correct; count them if you will :)

Comment: Dam yeah, you are right!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have interrupted the parentheses for the if statement. Is is_page a function? Try:

```
<?php if(!is_page(9) || !is_page(52)) : ?>
```